# Getting the ID of text elements that were dynamically added

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an ASP page whithin which my user can load items into textboxes.
As the number of elements that will be loaded is unknown at the beginning, I use Javascript to create new textboxes as needed.

```
<script>

var numerosesion = 0;

function crearBoton()

    {
    $('#contenedor').append('<p>Sesion número: ');

    numerosesion = numerosesion + 1;
    $('#contenedor').append(numerosesion)

    $('#contenedor').append('</p>');

    $('#contenedor').append('<input type="text" name="TextBoxSession">');

}
```

So far this works as expected, whenever the user presses the "añadir sesion" button, a new textbox is created.

But now I find that I've coded myself into a corner, because I can't figure out how to get the strings that the user puts in the textboxes.

Normally, I'd use `document.getElementById('textbox_id').value`

However I can't figure out what is 'textbox_id' for dynamically created input boxes.

Is there either:

- a) a way to get the id's of any new elements?
- b) a way to assign id's based on the numerosesion variable? that way I    could just use a for loop to get them all
- c) a different way altogether that achieves this
  goal?

Thanks for your understanding and time. I've been using stack overflow for a long time and this is the first time that I was unable to find an answer to my problem.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll("input[name=TextBoxSession]")` to grab all the textboxes. This gets you a NodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the new inputs, select them by class and iterate the array of results. Check this snippet (i translated Spanish namings to English):

```js
var inputNumber = 0;

function createInput() {
    inputNumber = inputNumber + 1;
    $('#container').append('<p>Input number ' + inputNumber + '</p>');
    $('#container').append('<input class="new-input" type="text" name="TextBoxSession">');
}
// Get the input values and show them
function showInputValues() {
  var newInputs = $('.new-input');

  if( newInputs.length ) {
    for(i = 0; i < newInputs.length; i++) {
      $('#values').append('<p>Value of input '+ (i+1) +': '+ newInputs[i].value + '</p>');
    }
  } else {
    $('#values').append('<p>There are no text inputs</p>');
  }
  
}

$( window ).load(function() {
  
  $('#add-btn').click(function(){
    createInput();
  });
  
  $('#show-values-btn').click(function(){
    showInputValues();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<br>
<button id="add-btn">Add new input</button>
<button id="show-values-btn">Show inputs values</button>
<div id="values"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery

---

$(".objectclass")
this return an array of dom elements, later you can iterate that array
remember:

---

"." (dot) class selector
"#" (hashtag) id selector

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID tag to the element that you are dynamically creating. Be sure to escape the JavaScript quote by using single quotes, since you’re using them above.

```
id=“‘+ numerosesion+’”
```

Then, add the following:

```
onkeypress=“setCurrent(this.id); return false;”
```

Then:

```
var currentID = null; 
function setCurrent(id){ currentID = id; }
```

Then when you want to get the value, do:

```
document.getElementById(currentID).value
```